# How can I improve questions marked as duplicate?

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, quality-improvement

I am currently question banned, and thus are editing and revising all of my questions. But, a fair number of them are duplicates. How can I edit them to improve them and eventually relieve the question ban?

Comment: Answer some questions which get upvotes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If they really are duplicates then leave them alone.

If they aren't duplicates, but were closed because you failed to provide enough detail to distinguish them, then edit that detail into them. Then hope that someone will be kind enough to vote to reopen them.